# Magento Get arg_name in observer

Tags: magento

i can set up a observer to listen when one of the controller method tigger, however, i want to pass the parameter  to the observer, how can i get the parameter in observer? arg_value

thanks a lot

```
<events>
<controller_action_predispatch_mycompany_mymodule_controllername_recalculation>
<observers>
<mycompany_mymodule>
<class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
<method>processgo</method>
<args>
<arg_name>arg_value</arg_name>
</args>
</mycompany_mymodule>
</observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_mycompany_mymodule_controllername_recalculation>
</events>
```

Comment: This is not a feature of Magento, so you will have to read the config manually. Looks like you found this snippet: https://gist.github.com/herveguetin/3312869 - you will have to implement the helper yourself to use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try something like following

```html
<events>
    <event_to_observe>
        <observers>
            <observer_name>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model_ObserverClass</class>
                <method>observerMethod</method>

                <args>
                    <arg_name>arg_value</arg_name>
                </args>

            </observer_name>
        </observers>
    </event_to_observe>
</events>
```

```html
<?php
/**
 * Observer class
 */

class Namespace_Module_Model_ObserverClass {

    /**
     * Observer method
     * 
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function observerMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $args = Mage::helper('ecmessenger')->getObserverArgs($observer, get_class($this), __FUNCTION__);
        Mage::log($args, null, 'observer.log');
    }
}
```

Make sure here Mage::helper('ecmessenger') is the helper that you need to create and specify in config.xml

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: getObserverArgs is not a core method, you will have to implement it on your own. The code in the answer is taken from https://gist.github.com/herveguetin/3312869 where you will also find the helper implementation